# AWS CodePipeline Four stage tutorial- Rake not found error

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-codepipeline

i am running AWS CodePipeline as per Tutorial .

i am using GitHub for source stage.
i am using Jenkins for Build stage. the Jenkins is failed to build . below is  the log file from Jenkins:

**Jenkins Error Log:**

Started by an SCM change

Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MyDemoProject/workspace

[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] Job 'xxxxx-a701-4849-bce0-axxxxfxxbxx' received

[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] Clearing Workspace 
'/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MyDemoProject/workspace' before download

[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] Detected compression type: Zip

[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] Successfully downloaded the artifacts from CodePipeline

[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] File downloaded successfully

[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] Extracting

'/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MyDemoProject/workspace/DTpHgNb.zip' to '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MyDemoProject/workspace'

[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] File uncompressed successfully

[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson1215556432xxxxxxx.sh
+ rake

/tmp/hudson12155564322xxxxxxx.sh: 2: /tmp/hudson12155xxxxxxxx.sh: **rake: not found**

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] Publishing artifacts

[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] Build Failed. PutJobFailureResult

Build step 'AWS CodePipeline Publisher' marked build as failure

Finished: FAILURE

please help ! What is mean by Rake !

Comment: Raj, you need to install rake and the haml gem. From "Step 1: Set Up Prerequisites": You have installed Rake and the Haml gem for Ruby on the same computer or instance that hosts your Jenkins project.

Comment: tapichu , thank you so much for the help . i thought i have to install the plugin for the Jenkins , you made my day.